# Pass an argument back and forth between two templates in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, url-routing

I have an app that returns information from an API request to the user based on their search request. Lets call this template A. They can then click on a link at the bottom of the page which brings them to a "More games like this" page, template B, that uses the same API, but a different endpoint to display similar games. I want the user to be able to then click on any of the suggested game's titles and be brought back to template A, without having to do a search, and the page display the relevant information for the game that was clicked on.

I have tried using url routing, such as `{% url 'vgSearch' result.name %}` in the href of the link to return the user back to template A. Then pass the result.name argument back through the original template A view. But I'm totally stumped on how to have it "catch" that information and display the API results.

This is what I have:

views.py

```py
def search(request, name=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        raw_result = request.POST.get('search')
        space_result = raw_result.replace(' ', '-')
        dot_result = space_result.replace('.', ' ')
        qmark_result = dot_result.replace('?', ' ')
        back_result = qmark_result.replace('/', ' ')
        colon_result = back_result.replace(':', '')
        final_result = colon_result.replace('\\', ' ')
        request.session['final_result'] = final_result
    else:
        final_result = name
        request.session['final_result'] = final_result
    url = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games/%s' % final_result
    url_suggested = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games/%s/suggested' % final_result
    response = requests.get(url)
    response_suggested = requests.get(url_suggested)
    search_result = response.json()
    suggested_result = response_suggested.json()
    search_success = (response.status_code == 200)
    nostr = 'None given . . . '
    message = f'{final_result} was not found! Maybe try a different spelling? i.e. V instead 5'
    return render(request, 'VideoGames/videogames_search.html', {'search_result': search_result,
                                                                 'suggested': suggested_result,
                                                                 'success': search_success,
                                                                 'message': message, 'nostr': nostr})


# Displays VideoGames searchable games index with id #
def suggested(request):
    game = request.session.get('final_result')
    url = 'https://api.rawg.io/api/games/%s/suggested' % game
    response = requests.get(url)
    suggested_games = response.json()
    status_success = (response.status_code == 200)
    suggested_message = 'Click on any of these games\' titles to see more information:'
    return render(request, 'VideoGames/videogames_suggested.html', {'suggested': suggested_games,
                                                                    'success': status_success,
                                                                    'message': suggested_message})
```

Template A:

```html
{% block appcontent %}
  <div class="height">
<form class="text-center" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group text-white">
  <input type="text" id="search" name="search" required>
</div>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
{% if search_result %}
{% if success %}
<div class="results-container">
    <p>
      <strong>Game Title:<br><span class="result">{{ search_result.name|default:nostr }}</span></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Game ID:<br><span class="result">{{ search_result.id|default:nostr }}</span></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Realease Date:<br><span class="result">{{ search_result.released|default:nostr }}</span></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Game Rating:<br><span class="result">{{ search_result.rating|default:nostr }}</span></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>ESRB Rating:<br><span class="result">{{ search_result.esrb_rating.name|default:nostr }}</span></strong>
    </p>
    <strong >Developer(s):</strong>
    {% for devs in search_result.developers %}
    <p>
      <strong>
         <span class="result">{{ devs.name|default:nostr }}</span></strong>
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
    <div>
      <img class="game-img" src="{{ search_result.background_image|default:nostr }}">
    </div>
    <div class="desc-container">
     <p>
    {% autoescape off %}
      {{ search_result.description|default:nostr }}
    {% endautoescape %}
    </p>
    </div>
     <div class="suggested-container">
      <p class="link"><a
          href="{% url 'vgSuggested' %}" >{{ suggested.seo_text|default:nostr }}</a></p>
     </div>
  {% else %}
    <p class="err-msg"><em>{{ message }}</em></p>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Template B:

```html
{% block appcontent %}

    <br>

    <p class="click"><em>{{ message }}</em></p>

{% if success %}
<div class="row">
    {% for result in suggested.results %}
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card mx-auto mt-5 mb-5 bg-dark" style="max-width: 40rem;">
          <img src="{{ result.background_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="title card-title text-success"><a href="{% url 'vgSearch' result.name %}">
                {{ result.name|default:'None given' }}</a></h1>
            <p class="card-text text-white">{{ result.short_description|default:'None given' }}</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">
                Released {{ result.released }} - id#: {{ result.id|default:'None given' }}</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Two things, there's actually a game called "None". So whenever template A loads it shows results for that game. Secondly the error that I'm getting is `Reverse for 'vgSearch' with arguments '('ABZU',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['videogames/search/$']`. I'm assuming "ABZU" is the first suggested game. When template B loads correctly it shows about 10-20 suggested games. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this without it loading the game 'None' everytime someone goes to do a search initially. Thanks!

Comment: you can use ajax request - after click is performed on button send data from button value to first template.

Comment: I could, that's one option, but isn't there some way to pass it back to template A's view, as a parameter? Since I'm not including the data in the url itself, I'm not sure how I'd "incorporate" it within template A's view? And if I were to use Ajax, I'd still have to tell template A's view how to use it, since it calls it's view every time it loads.

Comment: you can collect the data from first template in some view function ,then render next template with collected data